# RabbitListener binding queue to multiple exchanges

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm looking to be able to bind a queue to multiple exchanges utilizing the RabbitListener annotation but so far have been unsuccessful.

What I have right now is:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value =
    @Queue(
        value = "${subscriber.queueInbound}", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false", exclusive = "false"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "all", durable = "true")
    ),
    containerFactory = "subscriberRabbitListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
    // do something
}
```

This will on start/re-connect auto create the queue defined as `subscriber.queueInbound` and bind this queue to a default `all` exchange.

I then have a Job that runs in the background that will then properly configure this queue and bind it to the multiple exchanges it needs to be configured for.

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this either through the `@RabbitListener` or somehow adjusting it so that upon re-connection have it configure the queue appropriately before re-listening.

Originally I was doing the queue configuration through Beans however this prevented startup of the application if RabbitMQ was not available which I resolved but would then result in it starting up and the queue configuration steps not be performed.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = {
        @QueueBinding(value =
            @Queue(value = "foo"), exchange = @Exchange("ex1"), key="foo"),
        @QueueBinding(value =
            @Queue(value = "foo"), exchange = @Exchange("ex2"), key="bar")
})
public void listen(String in) {

}
```

> Originally I was doing the queue configuration through Beans however this prevented startup of the application if RabbitMQ was not available which I resolved but would then result in it starting up and the queue configuration steps not be performed.

That implies you were doing something "illegal" during context initialization. You should not try to talk to RabbitMQ until the context is fully built.

Beans are only declared on the broker when the connection is first opened.

Comment: Yes I realized my error and am working to correct it, however I should of been more clear the exchanges I'm configuring the queue to will come from a configuration file so I won't know how many `@QueueBinding` to setup until run time.

Comment: Then it can't be done with the annotation; while the simpler `queues` property can use SpEL to return a `String[]`, e.g. `#{'${some.prop}'.split(',')}` the `@QueueBinding` annotation is too complex to implement something like that.